# How do I insert into boost::unordered_set<boost::unordered_set<int> >?

Tags: c++, boost

The following code fails to compile, but if I remove the commented line, it compiles and runs correctly. I was only intending to use boost because C++ doesn't provide a hash function for `std::unordered_set<int>` by default.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::unordered_set<boost::unordered_set<int> > fam;
    boost::unordered_set<int> s;
    s.insert(5);
    s.insert(6);
    s.insert(7);
    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
    fam.insert(s); // this is the line causing the problem

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I want to be more clear than I was in the OP. First I know that the idea of the `boost::unordered_set<>` is that it is implemented with a hash table, rather than a BST. I know that anything that is to be a template type to the `boost::unordered_set<>` needs to have a hash function and equality function provided. I also know that by default the `std::unordered_set<>` does not have a hash function defined which is why the following code does not compile:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::unordered_set<int> > fam;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I thought that boost provides hash functions for all their containers which is why I believed the following code **does** compile:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::unordered_set<boost::unordered_set<int> > fam;
    return 0;
}
```

So now, I'm not sure why boost code just above compiles, but the code in the OP does not. Was I wrong that boost provides a hash function for all their containers? I would really like to avoid having to define a new hash function, especially when my actual intended use is to have a much more complicated data structure: `boost::unordered_map<std::pair<boost::unordered_map<int, int>, boost::unordered_map<int, int> >, int>`. It seems like this should be a solved problem that I shouldn't have to define myself, since IIRC python can handle sets of sets no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `unordered_set` (or `_map`) uses *hashing*, and requires a hash operator to be defined for its elements.  There is no hash operator defined for `boost::unordered_set<int>`, therefore it cannot put such a type of element into your set.

You may write your own hash function for this.  For example, this is a typical generic hash approach, though you may want to customize it for your particular data.  If you drop this code into your example, it should work:

```
namespace boost {
  std::size_t hash_value(boost::unordered_set<int> const& arg) {
    std::size_t hashCode = 1;
    for (int e : arg)
      hashCode = 31 * hashCode + hash<int>{}(e);
    return hashCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew about this solution already worked for std::unordered_set. But I didn't want to provide a custom hash function and I thought that boost already provides hashes for all their containers. (That is why I switched in the first place.) Also, not that I asked this in OP, but how do you explain that it will compile if you comment the insert line out because the first line of main() still instantiates the boost::unordered_set<boost::unordered_set<int> >? If I replaced that line with std::unordered_set<std::unordered_set<int> > it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @redmoncoreyl In specializations of class templates, the member functions are not instantiated unless they are actually _called_.  By commenting out the insert, you're not hitting the requirement for hashing, so it compiles (but isn't super useful since you can only have empty sets.)

Comment: Okay, I do understand the compiling nuance now. So then, referring to my edit in OP, boost doesn't define the hash function for all of its containers. Are there any libraries that do? I really don't want to have to write a custom hash function for the complicated data structure in the OP's edit. Like I said in the edit, I would think this would be a solved problem considering python does this automatically without having do define a hash function.